# How to stop Host (A) records from being auto-created

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003

I have a server with a few IPs.  I only want ONE Host (A) record to point from its name to one IP, and not to any of the others, which I am using other names for.

I'm not sure what triggers it, but I can delete the extra Host (A) records and refresh and they're not there, and then come back a few minutes later and refresh and they're back.  It may have been that I did `ipconfig /flushdns` or cleared the server DNS cache, or maybe it's something else, but in any case, how can I stop it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way would be on the server in question in the Advanced TCP/IP settings under the DNS tab to uncheck the "Register this connection's addresses in DNS" for any NIC you DON'T want registered.

If you have a single NIC with multiple IPs then do the same thing, but then you'll need to add a static Host (A) record in DNS for the server to make sure an entry exists for the name/IP match you want used still.

[image: Register this connection...]